# Inflated layout overlaps content

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a custom bottom navigation menu as a LinearLayout. This LinearLayout and some activity views both have the tag:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

When I inflate my bottom menu, this is causing the menu to overlap the other content tethered to the bottom. To inflate, I use:

```
RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_list);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_menu, main,false);
main.addView(view);
```

Is there a good way to 'resize' the activity frame after inflating so the activity content is placed above the bottom menu instead of underneath it?

**EDIT: with the help of Roman Kolomenskii's answer I solved the issue. I added a (wrapped-content) LinearLayout to the bottom of my activity and set other items to be above that container, and changed my Java code to this:**

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_menu_container);
View bottomMenu = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_menu, container, false);
container.addView(bottomMenu);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding some container layout to the bottom of your activity with `android:height="wrap_content".` Replacing all `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` with `android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_container"` and then just adding inflated menu to this container.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you should implement the following layout structure:

```
        <RelativeLayout>

             <RelativeLayout> //pin this to the top of your custom menu
             </RelativeLayout>

             <YourCustomMenuLayout> //pin this to the bottom of the outer relative layout
             </YourCustomMenuLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```